# How do I help prevent my users from initiating a drag accidentally in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I have a collection view that I've subclassed that allows me to reorder the collection view items via drag and drop.  My drag code that sets up the pasterboard is currently in mouseDragged:

```
- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)aEvent {

    if(!dragInProgress) {
        dragInProgress = YES;

        NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];        

            ... setup pboard, declare types, setData ...
            ... create drag image ....

        [self  dragImage: image
                      at: position
                  offset: NSZeroSize
                   event: aEvent
              pasteboard: pboard
                  source: self
               slideBack: YES];
    }
}
```

I would like to only initiate a drag if the user has dragged for a certain length, so they don't initiate a drag accidentally.  Is there a setting to do this in Cocoa, or do I need to move this code to mouseMoved: and check the distance between where the drag started and where the mouse is currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `mouseDown:`, remember where the mouse went down (`locationInWindow`). In `mouseDragged:`, subtract the location of the mouse-down event from the location of the mouse-dragged event, and compare the difference to the size returned by `HIMouseTrackingGetParameters` with the `kMouseParamsDragInitiation` selector.

Comment: Your solution of recording the locationInWindow in mouseDown and comparing it to the locationInWindow on mouseDragged worked.  I didn't see where HIMouseTrackingGetParameters and kMouseParamsDragInitiation came into play though.  I just used a c distance function to compute the distance and compare it.

Comment: That function gives you the correct minimum distance to initiate a drag. If the user hasn't moved that distance, they're just holding down the mouse button.