# mouseUp not firing in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mouseup

I'm trying to implement drag&drop functionality in my app and I ran into a problem of my mouseUp event not firing. It fires just fine if I simply click and release on my view, but if I do drag, my mouseDragged 
event fires and that's it.

By trying different things I figured out that the problem is in my dragImage call, but I don't know how to solve it for now.

Here is my code:

```
-(void) mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
   isDragging = YES;

   if ([selectedCellRowIndex longValue] >= 0)
   {
      NSImage *im = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/UserName/Desktop/drag.png"];
      NSSize dragOffset = NSMakeSize(0.0, 0.0);
      NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];

      [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSTIFFPboardType]  owner:self];
      [pboard setData:[im TIFFRepresentation] forType:NSTIFFPboardType];

      [self dragImage:im
                   at:downPointRelativeToTable
               offset:dragOffset
                event:theEvent
           pasteboard:pboard
               source:self
            slideBack:YES];
  }
}
```

Does anyone know where my problem can be?! Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a tracking rectangle or tracking area on the view? I had something like this awhile back where my tracking area was moving another view into place and that view was essentially diving in front of the `mouseUp:` events.

Comment: Also, you might want to [use `HIMouseTrackingGetParameters` to avoid accidentally recognizing clicks as starts of drags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1472834/30461).

Comment: @PeterHosey: no...I don't have tracking areas there. As for the second suggestion, I'll try it...sounds interesting! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code snippet you're getting the `NSPasteboard` instance but not copying your data to it. That's required, otherwise your drag won't be initiated properly - that's probably why you'll never get the `mouseUp:` event.

The docs for [`dragImage:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/dragImage%3aat%3aoffset%3aevent%3apasteboard%3asource%3aslideBack%3a) state that

> Before invoking this method, you must place the data to be transferred
>   on pboard. To do this, get the drag pasteboard object (NSDragPboard),
>   declare the types of the data, and then put the data on the
>   pasteboard.

Comment: Thank you Jay, that was definitely a good catch! I added:    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSTIFFPboardType]  owner:self];
        [pboard setData:[im TIFFRepresentation] forType:NSTIFFPboardType];  to my code...However, it didn't fix the problem :(

Comment: Hmm.. that's what I usually forget. If it still doesn't show up as a drag did you log the coordinates involved (in particular `downPointRelativeToTable`)? Maybe it's just off-screen.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this with a simple NSView descendant. On mouseDown a drag operation was initiated and mouseUp never was triggered. Instead the call to super blocked until the drag operation was done (a local run loop obviously). Consequently I had to put my mouseUp handling in the mouseDown function after the call returned from super.

Comment: Local runloops to handle drags are [generally discouraged](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH6-SW18) since the application’s main thread is unable to process any other requests during an event-tracking loop and timers might not fire as expected (though e.g. the Sketch example handles drag operations that way, so there you go..)